# Topology Theorem on closure of a set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If A is a subset of a metric space X ,then A closure is a closed set and is a subset of every closed set containing A

Comment: What is your question? What is your definition of closure?

Comment: A closure is union of set A and derived set of A

Comment: A common way to prove two sets are equal is to prove each is contained in the other.  Have you tried that?  What have you tried?

Comment: Henno Bradsma What does A" and A' mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a metric space, for any subset $A$ we have $A'' \subseteq A'$ (in general spaces this might fail, but it holds in $T_1$ spaces), and a set $B$ is closed iff $B' \subseteq B$ (take this as the definition if you will).

Now defining $\operatorname{cl}{A}=A \cup A'$, as per the comments, we see
that $$(\operatorname{cl}{A})' = (A \cup A')' = A' \cup A'' \subseteq A' \cup A' = A' \subseteq \operatorname{cl}{A}$$

so that $\operatorname{cl}{A}$ is closed, and if $C$ is closed and $A \subseteq C$ we have $A' \subseteq C'$ and so

$$\operatorname{cl}{A} = A \cup A' \subseteq C \cup C' \subseteq C$$ as $C' \subseteq C$ because $C$ is closed, proving the final claim.

Comment: @user11870400 $A’$ is the derived set of $A$ and *its* derived set is $A’’$.

Comment: Thanku you very much

Comment: What is T1 spaces

Comment: Proof of A' subset of C'

Comment: @user11870400 if $A$ is a subset of $B$, the same relation holds for their derived sets. This is standard. $T_1$ spaces are not needed if you’re working in metric spaces.

Comment: Does A" subset of A' holds for metric space

Comment: @user11870400 yes, it does. Also standard.